# Buying a Kittel for oneself, is that a problem?

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, high-holidays

I heard of a minhag not to buy a Kittel for oneself. Does anyone know a source For this minhag? Also, how does one practically go about this, if there is no one else willing to spend the money on the person needing the Kittel?

Comment: The only source I have is your assertion. Perhaps you should ask the one who told you this what is his source?

Comment: Never heard of it.

Comment: Maybe that’s why the kallah buys it for the chosson?